# In Typed JS (Typescript/FlowType) how do you handle normalized objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript, normalization, flowtype, static-typing

Working on a project.  I'm starting with flow type because it's easier to implement piecemeal but eventually I plan to convert from flow to Typescript when we move from "proof of concept" into "prototype".  However, a solution to this problem in either should work in both flow or TS.

I'm writing a backend API which makes queries to a database.

Now, my query to the DB gives me this:

```
type OneMeeting = {
  location: string
  participants: Array<string>
}

const RawDataFromDB: Array<OneMeeting> = await getDataFromDB();
```

Here's the problem:

I want to consolidate that data, so that if all participants are identical, the zip codes are combined.

So, I want this:

```
type Meeting = {
  locations: Array<string>
  participants: Array<string>
} 

const RawDataFromDB: Array<OneMeeting> = [
  {
    location: "Trump Tower",
    participants: ["Kushner", "Trump Jr.", "Manifort", "Veselnitskaya"]
  },
  {
    location: "Mar A Lago",
    participants: ["Kushner", "Trump Jr.", "Manifort", "Veselnitskaya"]
  },
  { 
    location: "Mar A Lago",
    participants: ["Trump Sr.", "Abramovich"]
  }
]

const WhatIWantAtTheEnd: Array<Meeting> = [
  { 
    locations: ["Trump Tower", "Mar A Lago"], 
     participants: ["Kushner", "Trump Jr.", "Manifort", "Veselnitskaya"]
  }, 
  { 
    locations: ["Mar A Lago"],
    participants: ["Trump Sr.", "Abramovich"]
  }
]
```

Now, the way I had been converting from Raw Data to What I want was basically to sort() the participants in each meeting, create an object where the key is the JSON.stringified version of the participants array, and push the location values.  So there's an intermediate step where, instead of an array of meetings, there's an intermediate Object with an unknown number of keys, where the names of those keys cannot be determined in advance.

And for the life of me, I can't figure out how to type out that intermediate Object so that it doesn't throw a type error, without making it an "any" - which will then throw errors if I try to .sort() on an "any" value.

So, typescripterinos, how would you approach this?

-- Edit, this is how I normally would do the conversion from A->B.

```
const getWhatIWant = (rawData: OneMeeting[]): Meeting[] => { 
// what is the type I should use for normalized ?
let normalized: Object = rawData.reduce((pv: Object, curr: OneMeeting) => { 
    let key = curr.participants.sort().join(",")
    if(!pv[key]){
      pv[key] = {locations: [curr.location], participants: curr.participants}
    } else {
      pv[key].locations.push(curr.location)
    }
    return pv;
    }, {})
  return Object.values(normalized);
}
```

Comment: Slight suggestion, you know you can use `Meeting[]` instead of `Array<Meeting>`?

Comment: I did not!  Thank you!

Comment: 'without making it an "any" - which will then throw errors if I try to .sort() on an "any" value' - that shouldn't be the behavior of `any` - it's truly typeless. Do you have some weird setting in your tsconfig? Can we see your sort code?

Comment: Could you post your current JS code that achieves the conversion from `RawDataFromDB` to `WhatIWantAtTheEnd`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of the algorithm you describe, the intermediate object type you are looking for, should have an indexer from `string` to `Meeting` defined:

```
let map: { [participants: string]: Meeting } = {};
for (let m of RawDataFromDB) {
  let key = m.participants.sort().join(',');
  let existingMeeting = map[key];
  if (!existingMeeting) {
    map[key] = {
      locations: [m.location],
      participants: m.participants
    }
  } else {
    existingMeeting.locations.push(m.location);
  }
}
```

Or using `reduce` as you do in your sample, you just need to specify the indexable type as a generic parameter (the parameter representing the result type) to `reduce`

```
const getWhatIWant = (rawData: OneMeeting[]): Meeting[] => {
  // what is the type I should use for normalized ?
  let normalized = rawData.reduce<{ [key: string]: Meeting }>((pv, curr) => {
    let key = curr.participants.sort().join(",")
    if (!pv[key]) {
      pv[key] = { locations: [curr.location], participants: curr.participants }
    } else {
      pv[key].locations.push(curr.location)
    }
    return pv;
  }, {})
  return Object.values(normalized);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's what you really want, but here is a one liner code:

```
// Assuming that type Meeting  = { location: string[]; participants: string[]; }
const WhatIWantAtTheEnd: Meeting[] = RawDataFromDB
    .map(meeting => meeting.participants.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))) // Create a participant sorted list
    .filter((value, index, array) => index === array.findIndex(compValue => value.every(participant => compValue.includes(participant)))) // strip duplicates
    .map(sortedParticipants => ({
        participants: sortedParticipants,
        location: RawDataFromDB.filter(raw => raw.participants.every(participant => sortedParticipants.includes(participant))).map(e => e.location)
    }));
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be horrifically inefficient from a BigO standpoint? That's at least On^2

Comment: Horrifically inefficient, I can't tell. But, yes, this function is not optimized. If you really want to be efficient, you should manipulate those data directly in SQL. Otherwise, using map with some precaculated Array hash could be faster. (and to be honest, n² is not that slow)